# How to exctract all Hive's database sizes in Gb and bytes

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I need to get list of databases with their sizes in Gb and bytes, which existing in hive warehouse

I'am new to bash commands and hadoop ecosystem, so i just found this command:

```
hdfs dfs -du -h  /user/hive/warehouse/
```

And it gives back list of databases, but sizes is actual sizes (mb, gb) and so on. I need code, to convert all those sizes to gigabytes and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-h` flag of `du` to get bytes rather than the **h**uman-readable version.

Also, this is only a list of HDFS paths, and will not include external Hive tables or partitions, which are only discoverable from querying the Hive metastore database server.